# Getting text from a text pane in a scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm just a beginner in Java.
Here's my problem :

I created a scrollable field of text with this code **(1)**:

```
jZone_Text = new JTextPane();
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jZone_Text);                               
jZone_Text = new JTextPane();                           
jPanelRecord.add(scrollPane);
scrollPane.setBounds(20, 70, 550, 190); 
scrollPane.setVisible(false);
```

Then I would like to get the text from my JTextPane and write it in a .txt file
So I did this **(2)** :

```
try {   
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\memo.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
    PrintWriter fichierSortie = new PrintWriter (bw); 
    fichierSortie.println (jZoneText.getText()+"\n "); 
    fichierSortie.close();

    }catch (IOException e2){
    }
```

But when I try, it creates my memo, but it's blank.

I tried to use the (2) code, and asked to get the text from a textfield which is not in my scrollable pane and it works perfectly..

I think that I can't get the text from a textpane which is in my scrollPane... Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating jZone_Text twice in (1). The second jZone_Text is not the one in the scroll pane thus it is empty. Replace with :

```
        jZone_Text = new JTextPane();
         scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jZone_Text);                              
         jPanelRecord.add(scrollPane);
         scrollPane.setBounds(20, 70, 550, 190);    
         scrollPane.setVisible(false);
```

Also, it is called jTitre_Text in (2), I'm assuming it's a typo

Comment: Thank you so much !! I didn't saw that mistake :-)

Comment: @XxRoboticaXx Please click the checkmark to validate the answer, otherwise this question will appear as unsolved

Comment: correct. and vote for good answers ;) this is how this board works :)

Comment: I had to wait 15minutes before saying it's solved :) thanks for reminded me.

Comment: I can't vote for you guys, I'm reputation 1, I have to wait until I'm 15 apparently

Answer (score 1):

You create an empty `JTextPane()`

Fill it with a string, and then use `.getText()` to get this "myString"

and btw: do not create a `new JTextPane()` in line 3 ;)

Comment: Thank you too !! x) I was too focused on the (2)